# Cassandra: How to know if operation was insert or update

Tags: cassandra, insert-update

In order to minimize number of queries I use only UPDATE method in my application:

```
UPDATE lp_registry.domain SET dr = ?, ud = dateOf(now()) WHERE d1 = ? AND d2 = ? AND d3 = ?
```

If a row with corresponding primary key d1,d2,d3 doesn't exist, then it is automatically created and that is what I want.

But what I also want is to know, if the row was inserted or updated. I've read in [cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html) about IF EXIST and 'applied' result. However this:

```
UPDATE lp_registry.domain SET dr = ?, ud = dateOf(now()) WHERE d1 = ? AND d2 = ? AND d3 = ? IF EXISTS
```

won't peform to operation if the row doesn't exist.

Is there any way how to do UPSERT without (SELECT and (INSERT or UPDATE)) and keep a track about insertion or update of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, you can't determine if a write performed a new insert of a row or an update to an existing row.  As you note, you can do this yourself by performing a read-before-write, but then you have introduced a performance hit on every write.

By design, Cassandra performs Upserts.  This performance optimization allows the Cassandra DB engine to write data without checking (reading) if it already exists.

`If EXISTS` is a form of Light-Weight Transactions [LWT](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html).  They are often used for optimistic concurrency control and have increased latency (up to fourfold) due to the implied read-before-write.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing, headline says to know operation.
In detail you say, you want uniform query that you can use for insert or update.

In cassandra update and insert are samething.

Just fire insert Query with full row everytime (all columns), if it exists, it will be updated based on primary key.

If it doesn't exist, it will be inserted.